# Mapping Keys with directory type in VIM

Tags: vim

I wonder if I can quickly edit some specific files based on project structures. For example if the folder identified as Laravel project this keymap will activated:

```
" Laravel framework
if(artisan_exist)
  nmap <leader>lr :e routes/web.php<cr>
  nmap <leader>lca :e config/app.php<cr>
  nmap <leader>lc :e composer.json<cr>
  nmap <leader>len :e .env<cr>
endif
if(webpack_exist)
  nmap <leader>js :e webpack.mix.js<cr>
@endif
```

so what is the correct function for `artisan_exist` or `webpack_exist` so I don't need to use ctrlp or nerdtree because I think isn't necessary to tap many keys only to open those common files.

Comment: if(file_readable("webpack.mix.js")) is what you are looking for ?

Comment: `file_readable` is obsolete, replaced by `filereadable` use `:help filereadable` for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start Vim in a certain (project) directory, you can test relative file paths. For example, to check whether the file `webpack.mix.js` exists in the project root, use

```
if filereadable('webpack.mix.js')
    nmap ...
endif
```

There's also `isdirectory()`, and `glob()` if you need to search entire subdirectories.

---

If this is for certain files, opened from any running Vim instance, and the mappings should be local to the file (and not only dependent on the *filetype*, for which Vim has a built-in detection and handling), you need a more fine-granular approach, usually called a *local vimrc*:

### Central configuration

If it's okay to configure the specific commands / local exceptions centrally, you can put such autocmds into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/dir/* setlocal ts=4 sw=4
```

It is important to use `:setlocal` instead of `:set`, and likewise `:map <buffer> ...` and `:command! -buffer ...`.

On the other hand, if you want the specific configuration stored with the project (and don't want to embed this in all files via *modelines*), you have the following two options:

### Local config with built-in functionality

If you always start Vim from the project root directory, the built-in

```
:set exrc
```

enables the reading of a `.vimrc` file from the current directory. You can place the `:set ts=4 sw=4` commands in there.

### Local config through plugin

Otherwise, you need the help of a plugin; there are several on vim.org; I can recommend the [localrc plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393) (especially with [my own enhancements](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-localrc/tree/enhancements)), which even allows local filetype-specific configuration.

<sup>Note that reading configuration from the file system has security implications; you may want to `:set secure`.</sup>